# Batch file : git checkout branch using variables

Tags: git, batch-file

I have an issue to set up this batch.
I want to get to my project directories, git fetch -all, switch branch to develop, pull, and go back to my actual branch 
For now I have succeded in doing so, but **is's impossible to checkout a branch using variables** I don't know why..

In short what I want to achieve is (on branch develop):

```
set current_branch=custom
git checkout %current_branch%
```

Here is the complete batch file

```
@echo off
SET project_array="c:\example\project01" "c:\example\project02"
for %%a in (%project_array%) do (
    echo ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    echo fetching datas for project at: %%a
    cd %%a
    @echo on
    for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('git branch --show-current') do set current_branch=%%i
    git fetch --all
    git checkout develop
    git pull
    git checkout %current_branch%
    @echo off
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: you need a delayed expansion

Comment: Or do not assign `%%i` to a variable but use it directly (`git checkout %%i`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (not tested):

```
@echo off
SET "project_array="c:\example\project01" "c:\example\project02""
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (%project_array%) do (
    echo ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    echo fetching datas for project at: %%a
    cd %%a
    @echo on
    for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('git branch --show-current') do set current_branch=%%i
    git fetch --all
    git checkout develop
    git pull
    git checkout !current_branch!
    @echo off
)
PAUSE
```

More on [Delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)